# How do I detect errors in rename column statement in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error, rename

```
column_mapper = {'DAILY_WELL_DRY_OIL_BBL': 'OilRate',
                 'PRODUCED_GAS_GAS_MMCF': 'GasRate',
                 'PRODUCED_WATER_BBL': 'WaterRate',
                 'DATE_': 'Date'}

df.rename(columns=column_mapper, inplace=True)
```

This does not work, I am not able to locate systax error in this.

Rest of the program works without column name change statement is removed. Can someone hlep?

Comment: There is no syntax error in the shown code, please provide a [mre] and the complete error traceback.

Comment: Would you show a sample of your df please?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the solution you have written which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.